# Get user email in windows 10 universal app

Tags: windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to build a control that the user can use to send feedback to developer. I am using email as a delivery method and I leverage sendgrid email service for this. Now I want to know the users email address so I can respond back to the user's concern. I am not sure how to get the user's email in window 10. Any help or pointers please?

Comment: There is probably no general way to do this, though Windows 10 has had it's share of privacy concerns so perhaps I'm wrong.  Ask the user for permission to have the email address.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is to have the user login with their email address when opening the app so you have an email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to use the sharing approach that has been introduced with Windows 8 - instead of writing and maintaining your own mail functionality and trying to access additional user data.

Have a look at the existing and built in e-mail functionalities. They make use of the user's connected mail accounts and the mail app. This way you don't need to worry about handling the message transmission or anything but rather hand the information over to the mail client. This way you also know how to reply back. 
And as a bonus, the user can still access their message via the Sent Mails folder :)

There is a specific class for that, the EmailMessageClass (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmessage.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) as well as a dedicated guide with code example. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269391.aspx

Essentially you can prepopulate the Mail fields with necessary app information where applicable. The user gets to choose which accounts he wants to send the mail from, but it will open in the mail client.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. This might work, my only concern about the user experience is making the user leave my app. I guess I will try and see how this works in my developer machine.

Comment: I tried your option seem to work. It open up a list of mail client that are installed so i think it is better idea than trying to get the user information

Comment: Cool, glad to hear! =)

Comment: Also, the user won't leave your app for long, only until the email is sent - then they are sent back to your app rather than the mail app. :)

Comment: Worked out Well. Thank you for the suggestion. One less hassel to worry about